# Add selectListener to table in SWT

Tags: java, swt

In SWT I want to show a `Table` with 4 columns: 1st a number, 2nd a String, 3rd a checkBox and 4th a radio button. 
Once all rows are set, I want to add another row for 3rd column (check all/none), and 4th column (clean radio selected).

This is the code (It compiles, but I haven't tested, yet):

```
//Create table 
Table table = new Table(layoutComposite, SWT.BORDER); 
table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL | GridData.FILL_VERTICAL));

String[] tableItems = new String[] {"", "Player", "Show", "Highlight"};
int[]  tableSizes = new int[] {30, 150, 20, 20}; 

// Header Columns and sizes for table 
for (int i = 0; i < tableItems.length; i++) { 
    TableColumn tableColumn = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tableColumn.setText(tableItems[i]);
    tableColumn.setWidth(tableSizes[i]);
}
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
table.setLinesVisible(false);

// Create items (void)  
for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
    new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
}

TableItem[] items = table.getItems();

// Check and Radio Buttons 
Button[] checks = new Button[items.length + 1];
Button[] radios = new Button[items.length + 1];

// Add elements 
for (int i = 0; i < items.length + 1; i++) {
    // Pos and Player only in first items.length rows  
    if (i < items.length) {
        items[i].setText(0, String.valueOf(positions.get(i).getPos()));
        items[i].setText(1, positions.get(i).getPlayer().getPlayerName());
    }
    TableEditor editorCheck = new TableEditor(table); 
    checks[i] = new Button(table, SWT.CHECK);
    checks[i].pack();
    checks[i].setSelection(true); 
    editorCheck.minimumWidth = checks[i].getSize().x; 
    editorCheck.setEditor(checks[i], items[i], 2);

    TableEditor radioCheck = new TableEditor(table); 
    radios[i] = new Button(table, SWT.RADIO);
    radios[i].pack();
    radios[i].setSelection(false);
    radioCheck.minimumWidth = radios[i].getSize().x; 
    radioCheck.setEditor(radios[i], items[i], 3);
}

table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.detail == SWT.CHECK) { 
            if (e.item instanceof Button) { 

                // TODO: 
                //   Get checked item selected 
                //   If last row (ie: == checks[items.length]), select or unselect all check related buttons 
                // 

                //((Button)e.item).get  //  Problem here!!!! 
            }
        }
        else if (e.detail == SWT.RADIO) { 
                // TODO: 
                //   Get radio selected 
                //   If last row (ie: radios[items.length]), clean selected item (if any)

        }


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.widgetSelected(e);
    }
});
```

Now I need to add a Listener over check and radio buttons. My question is: How do I know which check or radio button is selected? 
should I do something like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) { 
    if (e.item == checks[i]) { // found selected 
        if (i == checks.length -1 ) { // last one 
            // Select or unselect all
        }
        // doStuff () ; 
    }
}
```

If this is correct, Is there an easy way to know which is selected? If not, how can I do it?

Any other hint will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a selection listener to each checkbox and radio button after you create them:

```
    checks[i].addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
         // your code here...

         // get the current checkbox/radio button from the event:
         Widget src = event.widget;
         // ...
      }
    });
```

do the same with radio buttons:

```
    radios[i].addSelectionListener(...);
```

i hope this helps you. enjoy.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this way. Nevertheless, is this solution as efficient as adding one only listener for whole table? Which would be better?

Comment: adding a listener to the table does not catch the events from the buttons

Comment: Well, it think it does: [example1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DetectaselectionorcheckeventinatableSWTCHECK.htm) and [example2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTTableSimpleDemo.htm)

Comment: what you have there is not done with TableEditor, is just a table with SWT.CHECK flag.

Comment: Yes, I know. I've been trying to find another example, but I didn't succeed. The only one I found (I partly copied it) is [this one](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet126.java), but it does not have a listener implementation. Thanks a lot xD

Comment: [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratesTableEditor.htm) is an example for you